# Why does this Perl script give me a "Use of uninitialized value in addition (+)" error

Tags: perl

The program below should take an array and compress it so that there are no repeated products and add up the totals, so:

```
A B B C D A E F
100 30 50 60 100 50 20 90
```

Becomes:

```
A 150
B 80
C 60
D 100
E 20
F 90
```

The code below runs and works the way I want it to:

```
#! C:\strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;

my @firstarray = qw(A B B C D A E F);
my @secondarray = qw (100 30 50 60 100 50 20 90); 
my @totalarray; 
my %cleanarray; 
my $i;

# creates the 2d array which holds variables retrieved from a file
@totalarray = ([@firstarray],[@secondarray]);
my $count = $#{$totalarray[0]};

# prints the array for error checking
for ($i = 0;  $i <= $count; $i++) {
    print "\n $i) $totalarray[0][$i]\t $totalarray[1][$i]\n";
}

# fills a hash with products (key) and their related totals (value)
for ($i = 0;  $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $cleanarray{ $totalarray[0][$i] } = $cleanarray{$totalarray[0][$i]} + $totalarray[1][$i];
}

# prints the hash
my $x = 1;
while (my( $k, $v )= each %cleanarray) {
    print "$x) Product: $k Cost: $cleanarray{$k} \n";
    $x++;
}
```

However before printing the hash it gives me the "Use of uninitialized value in addition (+)" error" six times. Being very new to Perl (this is my first Perl program outside of a text book), can someone tell me why this is happening? It seems like I have initialized everything...

Comment: You have never initialized `@cleanarray` ... the error message is telling you *exactly* what the problem is.

Comment: I dare say you might want to take a look at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and maybe even [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html). A lot of problems can be avoided by having a clean data structure and accessing it appropriately.

Comment: This code should have died with the error `Global symbol "%cleanarray" requires explicit package name at ...`. So, it is highly unlikely that you have posted the code you actually use.

Comment: @TLP - you are correct, I posted `@cleanarray`, in my code it is `%cleanarray`, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives me compile errors in these lines:

```
my @cleanarray;
```

It is a hash.

```
my %cleanarray;
```

And here:

```
$cleanarray{ $totalarray[0][$i] } = $cleanarray{$totalarray[0][$i]} + totalarray[1][$i];
```

You missed the sigil of `totalarray`. It is `$totalarray[1][$i]`

The undefined message it is because `$cleanarray{$totalarray[0][$i]}` doesn't exists. Using the shorter:

```
$cleanarray{ $totalarray[0][$i] } += totalarray[1][$i];
```

will work without warnings.

Comment: Perfect, that worked. The first compiler error was, again, me failing to work with Stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using cleanarray as a hash but it is declared as an array

Answer (score 0):

You may find you prefer this reorganization of your program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @firstarray = qw (A B B C D A E F);
my @secondarray = qw (100 30 50 60 100 50 20 90); 

# prints the data for error checking
for my $i (0 .. $#firstarray) {
  printf "%d) %s %.2f\n", $i, $firstarray[$i], $secondarray[$i];
}
print "\n";

# fills a hash with products (key) and their related totals (value)
my %cleanarray; 
for my $i (0 .. $#firstarray) {
  $cleanarray{ $firstarray[$i] } += $secondarray[$i];
}

# prints the hash
my $n = 1;
for my $key (sort keys %cleanarray) {
  printf "%d) Product: %s Cost: %.2f\n", $n++, $key, $cleanarray{$key};
}
```